# using facebook requests

Tags: php, facebook, sdk

`Can I send a request to friend from app without users promting to do so?` do i need special `permission?`

If I cannot send request from app without asking for it - can I ask user to send request to a friend without letting him choose which one? (app would specify to which he can send, using it for a game).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can do this without any extended permissions. Check out the Facebook Dialog [documentation for requests](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/) which explains and shows how the requests channel works with the Graph API Dialogs.

This sample also shows various ways of using app requests via Facebook's [JS SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/).

```
<h1>requests</h1>
<button id="send-to-many">Send to Many</button>
<button id="custom-filters">Custom Filters</button>
<button id="send-to-one">Send to One</button>
<button id="send-app-to-user">Send App-to-User</button>
<button id="list-pending">List Pending</button>
<button id="clear-pending">Clear Pending</button>
<button id="clear-prompted">Clear Prompted</button>

<script>
document.getElementById('send-to-many').onclick = function() {
  FB.ui({
    method: 'apprequests',
    message: 'You should learn more about the @[19292868552:Platform].'
  }, Log.info.bind('send-to-many callback'));
}

document.getElementById('custom-filters').onclick = function() {
  FB.ui({
    method: 'apprequests',
    message: 'Have you heard about @[184484190795:Rell]?',
    data: 'invite-to-rell-42',
    filters: [{name: 'Daaku', user_ids: ['1677846385']}, 'app_non_users', {name: 'Games People', user_ids: [703, 6203644]}]
  }, Log.info.bind('send-to-many callback'));
}

document.getElementById('send-to-one').onclick = function() {
  FB.ui({
    method: 'apprequests',
    message: 'A request especially for @[1677846385:Daaku].',
    to: '1677846385',
    data: 'send-to-one-42'
  }, Log.info.bind('send-to-one callback'));
}

document.getElementById('send-app-to-user').onclick = function() {
  FB.api(
    '/me/apprequests',
    { message: 'From the app to the user.' },
    'POST',
    Log.info.bind('sent app-to-user request'));
}

document.getElementById('list-pending').onclick = function() {
  FB.api('/me/apprequests', Log.info.bind('pending requests'));
}

document.getElementById('clear-pending').onclick = function() {
  FB.api('/me/apprequests', function(response) {
    var ids = [];
    for (var i=0, l=response.data.length; i<l; i++) {
      FB.api('/' + response.data[i].id, 'DELETE', Log.info.bind('clear requests'));
    }
  });
}

document.getElementById('clear-prompted').onclick = function() {
  FB.api(
    prompt('Enter the ID of the request to delete:'),
    'DELETE',
    Log.info.bind('delete request'));
}
</script>
```

Comment: When did you implement the "name" parameter in the filters? :-)

Comment: Not sure - I often use [fbrell](http://fbrell.com/) for reference as a coworker of mine built it awhile back.

Comment: Hmmm fair enough. By the way, for the OP's first question...I don't think it's possible for the app to send app-to-user request for a friend.